# How to deserialise a json schema using Java and Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Environment: Java 19, Jackson-databind 2.14.1, com.networknt.json-schema-validator 1.0.78

I have a json schema,

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema#",
  "title": "Starbase Register",
  "description": "A set of records that describe a starbase",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {

    "host": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Host Star System",
      "description": "This is the star system that this starbase resides in"
    },

    "construction_year": {
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "Year of Construction",
      "description": "This is the year that the starbase was first constructed",
      "minimum": 2200
    }

  },
  "required": [ "host" ]
}'
```

which I have modelled in a POJO,

```
public class RegisterSchema
{
  @JsonValue
  private String title;
  @JsonValue
  private String description;
  private SchemaProperties properties;
}
```

and

```
@JsonRootName("properties")
public class SchemaProperties
{
  @JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
      property = "type"
  )
  private List<RegisterType> fields = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I'm trying to model the RegisterType using JsonSubTypes,

```
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RegisterTextType.class, name = "string"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RegisterIntegerType.class, name = "integer"),
})
public interface RegisterType
{
  String getName();
  String getType();
  String getTitle();
  String getDescription();
}
```

with implementations such as,

```
public class RegisterTextType implements RegisterType
```

I'm stuck on what I should be putting into SchemaProperties for the field called "fields".
In the schema itself, those objects could be named anything, so I think I'm getting tripped up by the naming convention Jackson is using when converting from the JSON -> POJO.

I implemented some awful code in the SchemaProperties,

```
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setFieldDetails (String key, Object value)
  {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> data = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) value;

    String type = (String) data.get("type");

    if ("string".equals(type))
    {
      RegisterTextType field = new RegisterTextType();

      field.setName(key);
      field.setTitle((String) data.get("title"));
      field.setDescription((String) data.get("description"));
      field.setType(type);

      fields.add(field);
    }

    if ("integer".equals(type))
    {
      RegisterIntegerType field = new RegisterIntegerType();

      field.setName(key);
      field.setTitle((String) data.get("title"));
      field.setDescription((String) data.get("description"));
      field.setType(type);
      field.setMinimum((Integer) data.get("minimum"));
      field.setMaximum((Integer) data.get("maximum"));

      fields.add(field);
    }
  }
```

which works, but it looks pretty gross and will be painful to maintain if I decide to implement a custom schema. I'd really like to be able to use the JSON subtypes to create these objects without having to write a lot of code using @JsonAnySetter.

When I run this code I don't get an error - I just end up with an empty List (fields).

The @JsonSubTypes were working when I had a simple JSON schema with an array of objects, such as

```
{
  "properties": [
    "class": {
      "type": "string",
      "label": "Ship Class",
      "length": 100
    },
    "captained_by": {
      "type": "string",
      "label": "Captained By",
      "length": 100
    },
}
```

But I believe that fails validation.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and simple?

Comment: `JsonSubTypes` will only work with an array. You have a map so you have to write code to extract value from the map and create an object.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar ah, ok, I'll need to find another way then. Thanks!